# How to call Invoke-RestMethod in powershell for each JSON entry

Tags: powershell

```
$person = @{

  "Username"="Test3";
  "Password"="Test3";
}
$json = $person | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "http://testa.katest.com/CreateUsers/api/v1.0/Users" -Body $json
```

Above powershell script works perfect and also creates the username Test3 in the system:

But If I would like to call this Invoke-RestMethod for creating multiple users at the same time - What command should I use?

Comment: Does the POST support a json array of users?

Comment: There isn't enough info on the API to actually provide a solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can only assume information about your API, I can offer two potential ways to do this.

If the POST supports a JSON array, you can do the following:

```
$persons = @{
  "Username"="Test3";
  "Password"="Test3";
},@{
  "Username"="Test4";
  "Password"="Test4";
}
$json = $persons | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "http://testa.katest.com/CreateUsers/api/v1.0/Users" -Body $json
```

If POST only supports one json with one user, you can do the following:

```
$persons = @{
  "Username"="Test3";
  "Password"="Test3";
},@{
  "Username"="Test4";
  "Password"="Test4";
}
foreach ($person in $persons) {
    $json = $person | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "http://testa.katest.com/CreateUsers/api/v1.0/Users" -Body $json
}
```

Each method centers around creating an array of hash tables. Each hash table has a key-value pair for `Username` and `Password`. Then you can choose to either iterate or not before converting to JSON.